# Entity Framework 4 - How to Read Multiple Record Sets From A Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, poco

I have a very simple stored procedure which returns multiple record sets. All of the record sets have aliased columns so they all look the same.

E.g.

```
    SELECT TOP 10 FooId AS Id, Name As Name FROM Foos
    SELECT TOP 10 BarId AS Id, Name As Name FROM Bars
         ...
```

For my EF setup, i'm using POCOs and have my own DataContext (no code-generation).

Now, i have created a "Function Import" using the technique detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nihitk/archive/2010/04/23/ado-net-entity-designer-in-vs-2010-stored-procedure-return-type-shape-sensing.aspx).

But the problem is, it's creating a complex type with Id and Name, not a type that can hold multiple *collections* of Id and Name. Can EF not detect that i am returning multiple record sets?

So the stored proc gets executed properly, but the only records that come back are from the 1st select statement, the other ones are discarded. So i only get back 10 records.

Here's how im executing the SPROC in my custom DataContext:

```
public ObjectResult<SomeSimpleProc_Result> GetSomeStuff()
    {
        return base.ExecuteFunction<SomeSimpleProc_Result>("SomeSimpleProc);
    }
```

And the Return Result POCO:

```
public class SomeSimpleProc_Result
    {
        #region Primitive Properties

        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The end result is i want to an object which has 0-* objects in it (in the above case, 3 objects). Each object should have a set of simple objects in it (Id, Name).

I think the problem is definitely with the customization of the "Function Import". How should i be creating the complex type? Or should i be using "Returns a collection of Entities".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think multiple resut sets are not supported out of the box. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/03/26/ado-entity-framework-stored-procedure-customization.aspx) is a blog post about using them in EF v1. EF v4 also doesn't support them directly - comments in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/04/12/announcing-the-release-of-entity-framework-4.aspx) contains following statement by Danny Simmons (he used to be dev manager for EF and Linq-To-Sql):

> Unfortunately we weren’t able to get
>   full support for multiple results into
>   the product this time around.  We did,
>   however, add the method Translate
>   to ObjectContext which allows you to
>   materialize objects from a DataReader.
>   ...

Edit: To make this little bit up to date: EF 4.5 (.NET 4.5 + VS2012) [supports stored procedures with multiple result sets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-multiple-result-sets-from-stored-procedure.aspx) but at least in Beta it looked like the support is not implemented in UI and EDMX validation also complained about some problems but at runtime it worked correctly.

Comment: Ah Ha! Nice find. Okay, so looks like we have to revert to some "classic" ADO.NET to get the result sets. Dang. Same issue with update multiple records with a single transaction (have to use SqlCommand). Oh well, at least we know. Thanks.